# external js with .php extension(Code igniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

guys, I'm trying to get the instance using `get_instance` function but I'm facing some problem it always throws me this error

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_instance()`

I have a file called `english.php` and it has the following code:

```
<?php
$ci =& get_instance();
//$ci->load->helper('language');

$CI->load->helper('language');
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

?>
<!--alert("Hello world");-->
var messages = {
    CALENDAR_CREATE: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_creation'); ?>",
    CALENDAR_EDIT: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_edit'); ?>",
    CALENDAR_DELETE: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_delete'); ?>"
};
```

and I'm including it like this

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/scripts/dynamic/english.php"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Firstly I was not loading any helper or getting any instance in the above since I had it loaded the language helper in CI_COntroller but it started giving me error that lang is not defined so tried to use the get_instance function but that is giving me the above error.

Can anybody tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong ??

Comment: You cannot get the instance of CI outside of the application scope. Your english.php is getting by http request and hence it is outside of the scope. Instead of this, you can create JS constants in your view and assign them to ```messages``` object.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Changed this line

```
$ci = &get_instance();
```

Comment: Can you share you english.php file code. Also where it is save and i haven`t seen any class name and __construct() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
<?php
$CI =& get_instance();
//$ci->load->helper('language');

$this->CI->load->helper('language');
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

?>
<!--alert("Hello world");-->
var messages = {
    CALENDAR_CREATE: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_creation'); ?>",
    CALENDAR_EDIT: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_edit'); ?>",
    CALENDAR_DELETE: "<?php echo lang('calendar_reminder_delete'); ?>"
};
```

Comment: this also does not helps. It's still throwing the same error `
 Call to undefined function get_instance()`

Comment: you can do this thing in view file itself, do you have any other purpose to write it in php file and import it in view like js?